# 70-80s (?) book about a military man who is a new person every day

Tags: story-identification, novella

This was a novella length book I read maybe forty years ago. It **might** have been an Ace double but I'm not 100%,

There was a Earth military intelligence officer based on another planet and (I don't remember how it happened) he wakes and heads to the base from his quarters. Alarms sound at the sentry point and he is taken prisoner, he is astonished to see he is actually one of the natives and he's held in the cells.

The next day he wakes in another body (maybe female but I'm unsure) and tries to work out what's happening, this continues daily but he succeeds in contacting his partner/wife and they learn the same thing is happening to her.

I think it also turns out a good few people are also walking around with his mind in them and they too are trying to go to army bases and getting arrested trying to enter.

He arranges code words and rendezvous with his girl and next day they both meet in that day's bodies. She is, this time, a man. Protagonist thinks to himself that things are going to get very strange regarding their sex life.

Comment: Three questions today have been about someone being a different person every day, but the descriptions are varied. I wonder if they're connected though?

Comment: The connection is probably "Ah, that makes me think of a similar story, I wonder what it was?"